# How to assign a completion handler to another in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an issue in Completion handler.

I have a method as below

```
-(void)authenticationRealmWithCompletion:(void (^)(AuthenticationRealm *authenticationRealm, NSError *error))completion realmId:(NSString *)realmId postDictionary:(NSDictionary *)postDictionary{
//my code
    }
```

Now I declared a variable as below

```
typedef void(^completionHandler)(AuthenticationRealm *authenticationRealm, NSError *error);
```

Now I want to assign as below

```
-(void)authenticationRealmWithCompletion:(void (^)(AuthenticationRealm *authenticationRealm, NSError *error))completion realmId:(NSString *)realmId postDictionary:(NSDictionary *)postDictionary{
[completion copy];

//**HERE**..... Error Line
completionHandler(completion);   

//my code



 }
```

But I am getting error as `Redefinition of 'completion'`

Please suggest how to assign completion handler to another.

Comment: `self.completionHandler = completion`?

Comment: @Larme sorry I am in Objective-c.

Answer (score 3):

To assign completion handler you have to create property
 of completion handler.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) completionHandler completion;
```

Then in your method assign using below code.

```
self.completion = completion;
```

**Update**

Method also be define as

```
-(void)authenticationRealmWithCompletion:(completionHandler)completion
                             realmId:(NSString *)realmId
                      postDictionary:(NSDictionary *)postDictionary{

self.completion = completion;

}
```